# how to filter records on a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hey I am trying to find a way to get my post records filtered. I only want to display records that are not older than the day before yesterday. I come up with this line of code,

```
Post.where(:course_id => current_user.courses & :date > (Date.yesterday-1))
```

but I receive this error:  `can't convert Symbol into Array`

Thx for your time

Comment: Getting the day before yesterday might be a little less confusing written as `Date -2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use an ampersand between multiple hash items, and you must use strings to do any less-than, greater-than, etc.

```
Post.where("course_id in (?) and date > ?", current_user.courses, Date.yesterday - 1)
```